# wkhtmltopdf is not rendering the javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm have got a page I want to print using an automated tool.

According to the docs and other posts, printing with javascript is supported with wkhtml to pdf.

Below is the full script I'm using.

> wkhtmltopdf.exe --no-stop-slow-scripts  -O landscape --javascript-delay 3000 https://stage-plan.com/stageplan/plan/bccfbd53-8b89-4401-b08a-95ea8af57361#hideScrollDownMessage c:\page.pdf

From this, I get a PDF with just a blue box, where as the actual [web page](https://stage-plan.com/stageplan/plan/bccfbd53-8b89-4401-b08a-95ea8af57361#hideScrollDownMessage) shows some pcitures which should be printed

I don't understand why this isn't printing my webpage to pdf. Is there something wrong with the command I'm using

I'm using Windows 2016 Server and version 0.12.4 (32 bit version)

Comment: Couldn't say for sure.  Try https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wkhtmltopdf-general and https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues because those people know a lot about the situation with that tool.

Comment: @user1329482, I've looked there, but I've seen comments that it is best to ask these questions here at SO :S Thank you though, I will try and post at GitHub as well